# How to allow Facebook Authentication to work on both localhost:3000 and my domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication

My situation is simple, I'm allowing users to authenticate on my Rails 4 application using Facebook.

In my Facebook settings, I have allowed `localhost:3000` to be my `Site URL`.

[image]

Locally, I can login and use my authentication just fine. But if I want to test this out in production, I need to change my site URL and the authentication no longer works on `localhost:3000`.

How can I tell Facebook to allow authentication on both `localhost:3000` **and** `foo.com`?

How do developers handle this very common situation?

Comment: This `common` situation is not very common actually, developer dont test at local and live server simultanneously. After the app is ready to use, either a new app is created (with changes in the app credentials in the code) or the site url is changed to the live server.

Answer (score 0):

Create two Facebook application: for production and for development. It's common practice.